# Excel VBA populate list box with searched dynamic range

Tags: vba, excel

My difficulty is this: I have a Excel spreadsheet where I need a UserForm ListBox to populate itself with some rows of data depending on previous user input.

So the UserForm should pick up the user's input in `Sheet1` (say it's `123abc`) and then search for similar results in `Sheet2`. The nearest results (probably a range of about five similar results) should then fill the listbox.

So it could return something like `123a`, `123ab`, `1235c`, and `1355abc` from the list

Hope this makes sense - thanks for your help in advance.

The code I've tried (and doesn't work, turns a 1004) with notes for clarification:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Dim cs As Worksheet
  Dim c As Range
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim code As Variant
  Dim co As String

Set code = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4") 'picks up user input
co = Left(code, 2) 'just takes first two letters of input to find similar

Set cs = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set c = cs.Range("A2:A20000").Find(co) 'find code (obviously :))

For i = 1 To cs.Cells(c.Offset(5, 0), 1).End(xlUp).Row Step 1
   If cs.Cells(i, 1).Value <> vbNullString Then Me.ListBox1.AddItem cs.Cells(i, 1).Value
Next i 'populate listbox

End Sub
```

Many thanks!

---

### EDIT

I have marked the below as the accepted answer, but for others browsing this, the problem still exists as to integrating this with the template Excel files, as it returns the error 'External table is not in the expected format'. I had to change `ThisWorkbook.FullName` to the **full template path** to remove another error too.

Comment: I'd consider writing a SQL statement that would search the sheet for you. Something like `"Select Top 5 from [Sheet2$] where [MyColumn] like *" & UserForm.TextBox & "*"` . You can use ADO to connect to your spreadsheet to return the results in a recordset. With the recordset, you can then populate the ListBox by iterating the recordset. Let me know if you'd like to see a demo.

Comment: @RyanWildry thanks for the suggestion - the only difficulty is that workbook is already large and slow, so I'm not 100% about the SQL. +1 for the suggestion though!

Comment: Running a SQL statement should be very fast, and it scales well with increasing size of the sheet. I've used it successfully with a several hundred thousand records with good results.

Comment: OK, cool. Could you put it in an answer so I can try it out and mark it as the accepted answer? Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the aforementioned example. The code is mostly commented with what is needed. Please feel free to ask any questions.

I did a quick performance test searching for a text string in a data set of about 65,000 records. It look less than a second.

Here's the code:

```
'Making these variable public so they don't need to be recreated each time
'Make sure you add a reference to ADO through the tool-->references menu
Public MyConnection As New ADODB.Connection
Public MyRecordset  As New ADODB.Recordset
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ColumnName As String: ColumnName = "[Number]" ' The name of the Column in Sheet2 you are searching for, it should have a header in row 1
    Dim SearchStr  As String: SearchStr = Left(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Value2, 2) ' This is what will be searched

    If MyConnection.State <> adStateOpen Then
        With MyConnection
            'Connection string below is assuming you are using an XLSX file 2007 or higher
            'It also assumes Sheet2 has column headers, e.g. HDR=Yes in the connection string
            .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & _
                                ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1';"
            .Open
        End With
    End If

    If MyRecordset.State = adStateOpen Then MyRecordset.Close ' Make sure recordset is closed when open
    MyRecordset.Open "Select top 5 " & ColumnName & " from [Sheet2$] where " & ColumnName & _
                     " like '%" & SearchStr & "%'", MyConnection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly

    Me.ListBox1.Clear ' Clear all entries from the listbox
    If Not MyRecordset.EOF Then MyRecordset.MoveFirst 'Move to start of recordset

    Do Until MyRecordset.EOF 'Loop recordset and add all the items
        Me.ListBox1.AddItem MyRecordset.Fields(0).Value
        MyRecordset.MoveNext
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: That looks brilliant. Not being totally up with SQL, how would I edit your answer so that it's not on a textbox change, but when the UserForm Initializes (and then pull the value from a range on Sheet1)?

Comment: Updated to use the first two characters, I've thrown this into a string called SearchStr.

Comment: this looks brilliant, yet it seems to throw an error when I try to `.Show` the UserForm, which kind of suggests to me that it won't `Initialize`?.... I've set the ColumnName to `"[Variant code]"` and Sheet1 to `"Code Input Sheet"`, not sure if I need to change `[Sheet2$]` to the correct sheet name either?.... Many thanks

Comment: You'd need to update the sheet name if different from sheet2. Keep in mind the sheet name must have a $ at the end for the sql statement.

Comment: I added the reference `Microsoft ADO Ext. 6.0 for DDL and Security` but I don't know if that's the right one....... changing the Sheet2 doesn't seem to make any difference, the error gives me a 424 Object required.....

Comment: You need to add Microsoft Active Data Objects 2.8 or 6.1

Comment: Sorted; the problem was also that I'd forgotten to put the Public functions in the right place - many thanks for your help!

Comment: One last ammendment (promise!) - as this is a shared server file I think I've got to put the `Data Sources` folder on the server. Where should I input the path in the code??

Comment: Update the DataSource in the connection string. ThisWorkbook.FullName returns a path, you'd be replacing that with the location of the file.

Comment: OK - I think the problem lies in the fact it's a template file - I get a run time error that it can't find the Object `N:\User\Documents\Workbook1.xltm` - it's looking in their documents rather than the source directory :(